# Unit Test a watcher inside a Pinia store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia, vitest

I am struggling to properly unit test a watcher inside my Pinia based store.

This is my store:

```js
export enum SidebarMode {
  Static = 'static',
  Overlay = 'overlay',
}

export const useLayoutStore = defineStore('layout', () => {
  const { width: windowWith } = useWindowSize();
  const sidebarMode = computed(() => windowWith.value >= 991 ? SidebarMode.Static : SidebarMode.Overlay);

  const sidebarCollapsed = ref(false);

  const sidebarOverlayActive = ref(false);

  function toggleSidebar() {
    switch (sidebarMode.value) {
      case SidebarMode.Static:
        sidebarCollapsed.value = !sidebarCollapsed.value;
        break;
      case SidebarMode.Overlay:
        sidebarOverlayActive.value = !sidebarOverlayActive.value;
        break;
    }
  }

  watch(sidebarMode, (newMode) => {
    if (newMode === SidebarMode.Static)
      sidebarOverlayActive.value = false;
  });

  return { sidebarMode, sidebarCollapsed, sidebarOverlayActive, toggleSidebar };
});
```

As you can see, the watcher monitors changes of the computed `sidebarMode` property and resets `sidebarOverlayActive` whenever the `sidebarMode` changes to static mode.

And `sidebarMode` on the other side relies on `useWindowSize()` from `@vueuse`.

To test the computed value, I did mock the `windowWith` using
`vi.spyOn(window, 'innerWidth', 'get').mockReturnValue(width);` and then test whether the correct `sidebarMode` was evaluated.

To test the watcher, I would need to trigger a change on the computed value. But I don't want to rely on mocking the `window.innerWidth` as this would mean the test would cover both, the computed value and the watcher.

So I would appreciate any inputs on how to properly test this watcher.

Is there a way to forcefully change to value of the computed value?
Or should I somehow mock the computed value?